# Will breathing through mouth result in any disorders?

Tags: breathing, health, nose

My nose is slightly bent. When I was born, I had an issue with breathing. My mom said that doctors had inserted a breathing tube in one of my nostrils. This tube may have caused the deformation. From childhood, I breathe through my mouth. Will there be an any problems in the future? Do I have to take any treatment? Please suggest.

Comment: can you make the question little more general, it might be flagged for personal medication.

Comment: I don't think this can be generalised. To generalise, he'd need to understand his problem deeply, which he does not. @roarer should consult his doctor as soon as he can - I'm sure it's not a good idea to breath with your mouth. You'll get infections, which are normally filtered in nose.

Comment: @TomášZato I totally agree with that.

Comment: Yes, you become more prone to infections. Would be ideal to consult a doctor so as to get your nose sorted out. I wonder why they didn't try to fix it when you were a child as that would have been much easier than now.